# Как выполнить авторизацию для моего приложения на C# через мой сайт wordpress?

Tags: c#, wordpress, аутентификация

Суть такова, человек запускает программу, и если человек не вошел в систему, она забрасывает его в браузер, где находится мой сайт wordpress, и отправляет его на форму авторизации, после авторизации она забрасывает его обратно в программу, которая получает пользовательские данные с сайта. Мне нужно как-то реализовать это на C# и на wordpress, я также прикрепил скриншот из paint, чтобы было немного понятнее

Нужна помощь с тем, как это реализовать (плагины, гайды и т.д.), спасибо

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Плагин сначала найдите для своего сайта, который поддерживает OAuth, либо простое получение токена JWT, а уже затем пишите клиент, который будет это использовать, даже браузер не нужен будет... Вот например, [первый попавшийся из интернета](https://wordpress.com/plugins/wp-rest-api-authentication).

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Так мне нужно именно через авторизацию сайта, т.к. там они покупают продукт и я не хотел бы их утруждать дополнительной авторизацией в приложении, лучше чтобы на сайт перекинуло, авторизовало и запомнило а дальше я уже сервер напишу который отдельной будет работать(

Comment: То, как клиент будет взаимодействовать с сайтом, зависит именно от сайта, как он настроен, что требует, и так далее. А открытие в дефолтном бразуере, в браузере самого приложения, или запрос логина и пароля - это уже, скажем так, дело десятое. Так что, сайт сделайте, чтоб тот принимал нужные данные, сделайте там OAuth, а затем пишите приложение. Сейчас случайно наткнулся на [это](https://melmanm.github.io/misc/2023/02/13/article6-oauth20-authorization-in-desktop-applicaions.html), думаю полезно будет почитать.

Comment: Логика в корне не верная. Не нужно никого "забрасывать в браузер". Нужно сделать авторизацию в своём приложении. А для безопасности использовать пароли приложений https://wp-kama.ru/handbook/rest/basic/authentication/application-passwords

Comment: @EvgeniyZ для ВП никаких плагинов не нужно. REST-API в ВП есть из коробки.

Comment: Да, забыл дать главное https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/using-the-rest-api/authentication/

Comment: Я уже сделал аунтетификацию через Oauth2